# SMTP connect() failed... while i am trying to send mail from my php file

Tags: php, email, smtp

i ve been trying to send mail from my php file, i got an error like this

```
**"SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0) SMTP connect() failed."**
```

i am in the deadline of my project, if anybody knows the solution or error what i have done over here, please share and help. 
i am sharing my code here.........

```
<?php
    require("C:/xampp/htdocs/conference/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");
    require("C:/xampp/htdocs/conference/PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 465; // SMTP Port
    $mail->Username   = "my email address"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "my password";        // SMTP account password

    $mail->SetFrom('my email address', 'xxxx'); // FROM
    $mail->AddReplyTo('my email address', 'xxxx'); // Reply TO

    $mail->AddAddress('someone email address', 'yyyy'); // recipient email

    $mail->Subject    = "First SMTP Message"; // email subject
    $mail->Body       = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through Google SMTP using PHPMailer.";

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo 'Message was not sent.';
      echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: try changing port number to 587 and restart your server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem,

Check whether your PHP is using **openSSL** extension or not...!

1. Edit your **php.ini** from your installed php folder
2. Search for **extension=php_openssl.dll**
3. The initial will look like this **;extension=php_openssl.dll**
4. Remove the ';' and it will look like this **extension=php_openssl.dll**
5. If you can't find the **extension=php_openssl.dll**, add this line **extension=php_openssl.dll**.
6. Then restart your Xampp or LAMP or APACHE server (depends upon which of these you're using).

Hope this method would solve your problem...

Answer (score -3):

There are double quotes in

```
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
```

Please remove the double quotes.

```
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP server
```

Comment: Try to lookover every variable in this document and see if it matches yours. Click [here](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md).

For example, your Username and Password shouldn't be in double-quotes too. Take your time and carefully read. 's are known to sneakily mess things up.


Also, please use ssl://smtp.gmail.com. This lets your program know that it should use an protocol.