# PHP mailer class not working with php - xamp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, phpmailer

I have the following code which is giving and error

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSendmail();
//Send mail using gmail

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com"; // GMAIL username
$mail->Password = "mypassword"; // GMAIL password

$mail->From = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Online Request";
$mail->AddAddress("receiver_email@gmail.com","myself");


$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
 $mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

   if(!$mail->Send())
   {
  echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  exit;
  }

 echo "Message has been sent";
  ?>
```

The error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP connect() failed.' in C:\Softwares\xampp\htdocs\email_testing\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php:1193
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 C:\Softwares\xampp\htdocs\email_testing\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(1036): PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Thu, 31 J...', '--b1_02dd62dba5...')
>
> 1 C:\Softwares\xampp\htdocs\email_testing\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(943): PHPMailer->postSend() #2 C:\Softwares\xampp\htdocs\email_testing\test.php(25): PHPMailer->send()
>
> 3 {main} thrown in C:\Softwares\xampp\htdocs\email_testing\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1193

im using xamp with php 5.3.8, apache 2.2.2.1, xamp ver 1.7.7

any ideas? appreciate the help

Comment: Can I assume your development machine has a working Internet connection?

Comment: yah it has a working internet connection.

Comment: What’s the reason of subsequent calls to `isSendmail` followed by `isSMTP`? If the `sendmail` is installed and configured, I would suggest you to remove `isSMTP()` call from your code.

Comment: is there a firewall or proxy blocking the port or ssl traffic?

Comment: Have you enabled the openSSL extension? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21068163/283366

Comment: @mudasobwa To use GMail, OP **must** use SMTP. I'd recommend removing the `IsSendMail()` line. Off topic; this utility's API is simply horrible. I highly recommend Swift over PHPMailer

Comment: ive removed isSMTP() still error and i also remvoved isSendmail and used isSMTP. i added code to catch exception catch (phpmailerException $e)
{
    return $error -> errorMessage();
} it is giving this error now Fatal error: Call to a member function errorMessage() on a non-object in C:\Softwares\xampp\htdocs\email_testing\test.php on line 30

Comment: @Alz It's `getErrorMessage()` but we already know what that is ("*SMTP connect() failed."*). I suggest you add `echo $mail->ErrorInfo` to your `catch` block.

Comment: @Phil i have used $mail->ErrorInfo the error it is showing is SMTP connect() failed. Any idea why?

Comment: can there be any issue in class.phpmailer.php? i have downloaded it from internet and used it first time. is there any configuration we need to do in that?

Comment: This error is usually caused by environment issues - blocking by your ISP's firewall, DNS failure etc. For gmail you should set `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 587`. I'd also guess you're using an old version (or you copied yoru code from an old example). Get the latest [from GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: @Synchro i have used the same link to download phpmailer, and i have tried tls as well but not working same error. 2014-07-31 07:50:02 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: OK, so it's an environment problem. I'd guess you have trouble doing `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` from that server (as the PHP user) too.

Comment: @Synchro yah when i use the command it gives same error "Connecting to smtp.gmail.com... Could not open connection to the host, on port 587: Connect Failed"

Comment: Well there you are - figure out what's blocking your access and PHPMailer will start working too.

Comment: @Synchro thank you for the help. do you have any suggestions what could be the cause of it?

Comment: Most likely DNS, outbound firewall, or possibly php.ini settings though that's unlikely because the telnet fails too. See if you can do name lookups for `smtp.gmail.com` from a command line.

Comment: i have done nslookup on command prompt replied non-authoritative answer: Name: gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com, Addresses: 2607:f8b0:4001:c03::6d, 74.125.142.108, 74.125.142.109, Aliases: smtp.gmail.com.   Any ideas guys.